# Laravel Output Associated Tags

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, associations, laravel-5.1

I have an application in Laravel 5.1, my application allows the user to add an article and choose a number of categories associated to that article.

I save the relationship between the article in an association table and I now want to output on the user's articles page all the articles the user has submitted but at the side of the title show the categories the article is within.

the articles page will list all the articles so the list has to be unique.

**my controller:**

```
public function index()
    {
        $articles = DB::table('articles')
                    ->leftjoin('w_relations','w_relations.article_id','=','articles.id')
                    ->leftjoin('articlecategories','articlecategories.id','=','w_relations.type_id')
                    ->where('articles.comp_id',Auth::user()->comp_id)->get();

        return view('advertiser/workshops', compact('workshops'));
    }
```

**my view**

```
<ul>
@foreach($articles as $a)
    <li>{{ $a->article_name }} | {{ $a->category_name }}</li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

**I thought the above would output**

```
Article 1 | History, Category, Category2
```

**but instead I get**

```
Article 1 | History Article 
1 | Category Article 
1 | Category2
```

I can kind of see where I'm going wrong but I don't know how to fix the query?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick solution to your problem,

1. Keep the query
2. Manipulate the output

So then **my view** would look like this:

```
<ul>
@foreach($articles as $a)
    <li>{{ $a->article_name }} 
    // inner loop on articles would only output category names
    // that match the current article
    // quite a labour if you ask me
    @foreach($articles as $x){
        @if($x->id == $a->id ){
            {{ $a->category_name }}
        @endif
    @endforeach
    </li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

I'm certain you can have a more elegant approach to this by taking advantage of **Laravel's Eloquent ORM**